# FaceDetection in python using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have written the following code in order to detect "presence of a face/faces" in python under OpenCV.

```
import cv2
import sys

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
     rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
     rval = False

while rval:
     rval, frame = vc.read()

     gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
     for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
         frame = cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

     # Display the resulting frame
     cv2.imshow('Preview', frame)

     key = cv2.waitKey(20)
     if key == 27: # exit on ESC
        break

cv2.destroyWindow("preview")
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I receive the following error :

```
   /usr/bin/python3.4  /home/yas/PycharmProjects/Ch10_OpenCV/Example.py
   init done 
   opengl support available 
   OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!empty()) in detectMultiScale, file    /home/yas/opencv-3.0.0/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp, line 1634
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/yas/PycharmProjects/Ch10_OpenCV/Example.py", line 32, in <module>
   faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
   cv2.error: /home/yas/opencv-  3.0.0/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1634: error: (-215) !empty()    in function detectMultiScale


  Process finished with exit code 1
```

As the result, the webcam window does not open and for sure no face is detected. I am working under Linux-Ubtunu and working with Python interpreter 3.4.3.

What does this error mean? How can it be solved? Thanks for sharing your opinions

Comment: May be the `'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'` file is not found, Provide the full qualified path

Comment: Thanks. The problem was as you mentioned! I manually download the xml file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shantnu/Webcam-Face-Detect/master/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml and added it to the current working directory.

The program now detect faces very well. However, could we verify is this xml file is one of python default distributions? Upon checking, I could not confirm this.

Comment: In case of any doubt you can download the cascade files from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades

Comment: Amazinj Zdar, very useful resource, I did not know about it Thanks. Can you kindly remind if one is interested to create a similar cascade classifier to detect an arbitrary object "let's say fruits" how this could be done? Where can I obtain more information about this please?

Comment: You can get help on designing your own cascade at http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html and http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `vc.release()` just before the last two lines. It would be something like:

```
vc.release()
cv2.destroyWindow("preview")
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```